# Is it possible to use reframe in dplyr to get the former behaviour of summarize?

Tags: r, dplyr, summarize

We've just upgraded from dplyr to version 1.1.0 and now we have a problem with summarize and unique. We're trying to use reframe instead.

the problem is that one variable is sometimes NA and sometimes a value, e.g.

[image]

With the old dplyr summarize behaviour, it would pick the non-nan value if there was one and otherwise it would keep it as NAN.

With reframe, it always keeps both the value and the NAN.

[image: output how it should look like]

Example 'old' code:

```
t <- buttons %>%
group_by(envIndex,predIndex) %>%
dplyr::summarize(predatorLocation= unique(predatorLocation)
```

Is it possible to use reframe to reproduce the former behaviour of summarize?

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would be easier to help you if you provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data. Please do not post an image of code/data/errors [for these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Just include the code, console output, or data (e.g. dput(head(x)) or data.frame(...)) directly.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question; one potential option would be to take the first non-NA value for each group, i.e.

Example data:

```r
library(tidyverse)

data(ChickWeight)

df <- ChickWeight %>%
  slice_head(n = 36) %>%
  mutate(Diet = ifelse(Chick == 1, NA, Diet),
         Diet = ifelse(Chick == 2 & Time < 16, NA, Diet))
df
#>    weight Time Chick Diet
#> 1      42    0     1   NA
#> 2      51    2     1   NA
#> 3      59    4     1   NA
#> 4      64    6     1   NA
#> 5      76    8     1   NA
#> 6      93   10     1   NA
#> 7     106   12     1   NA
#> 8     125   14     1   NA
#> 9     149   16     1   NA
#> 10    171   18     1   NA
#> 11    199   20     1   NA
#> 12    205   21     1   NA
#> 13     40    0     2   NA
#> 14     49    2     2   NA
#> 15     58    4     2   NA
#> 16     72    6     2   NA
#> 17     84    8     2   NA
#> 18    103   10     2   NA
#> 19    122   12     2   NA
#> 20    138   14     2   NA
#> 21    162   16     2    1
#> 22    187   18     2    1
#> 23    209   20     2    1
#> 24    215   21     2    1
#> 25     43    0     3    1
#> 26     39    2     3    1
#> 27     55    4     3    1
#> 28     67    6     3    1
#> 29     84    8     3    1
#> 30     99   10     3    1
#> 31    115   12     3    1
#> 32    138   14     3    1
#> 33    163   16     3    1
#> 34    187   18     3    1
#> 35    198   20     3    1
#> 36    202   21     3    1
```

Answer:

```r
# Chick 2 has both value and NA in reframed df
df %>%
  reframe(Diet = unique(Diet), .by = Chick)
#>   Chick Diet
#> 1     1   NA
#> 2     2   NA
#> 3     2    1
#> 4     3    1

# Potential solution
df %>%
  reframe(Diet = first(unique(Diet), na_rm = TRUE), .by = Chick)
#>   Chick Diet
#> 1     1   NA
#> 2     2    1
#> 3     3    1
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Does this approach solve your problem?